# Why print result is blank?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to print "the page" section, but the result is blank
this is .xhtml file made with primefaces :

```
<p:tabView id="tabview">
<p:tab title="Per Nasabah">
<div class="grid table-demo">
    <div class="col-12">
        <h:form>
            <div class="card">
                <div class="ui-fluid formgrid grid">
                    <div class="field col-12 md:col-4"></div>
                    <div class="field col-12 md:col-2">
                        <label><br/></label>
                        <p:commandButton styleClass="mr-2 mb-2" value="Submit" update=":tabview:invoice-content" partialSubmit="true"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field col-12 md:col-2">
                        <label><br/></label>
                        <p:commandButton styleClass="mr-2 mb-2" value="Cetak" type="button">
                            <p:printer target=":tabview:invoice-content" />
                        </p:commandButton>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field col-12 md:col-4"> </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </h:form>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="grid">
    <div class="col">
        <div style="margin-top: 10px" class="card">
            <h:form id="invoice-content">
                <div class="invoice-custom">
                    <!--The page-->
                </div>
            </h:form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</p:tab>
</p:tabView>
```

the command button :

```
<p:commandButton styleClass="mr-2 mb-2" value="Submit" update=":tabview:invoice-content" partialSubmit="true"/>
```

that is work,

But, the print button :

```
<p:commandButton styleClass="mr-2 mb-2" value="Cetak" type="button">
 <p:printer target="invoice-content" />
</p:commandButton>
```

The result print is blank

Answer (score 1):

You should reference the other form like `:invoice-content`.

See also: [How to find out client ID of component for ajax update/render? Cannot find component with expression "foo" referenced from "bar"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156/how-to-find-out-client-id-of-component-for-ajax-update-render-cannot-find-compo)

Comment: for update button, thats work. But for print button is nothing to print. blank page

Comment: @DenaAchmad Can you please create a [mcve] using https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces-test using the latest release of PrimeFaces?